# TextView does not get focus on talkback mode

Tags: android, android-tv, accessibility

I have an fragment in android TV application which has a lot of TextViews, some of them are focusable and the others are not.

When I turn on the talkback on the device, the views which are not focusable does not get accessibility focus, so their texts are not read to the user.

For example, here is a sample TextView I've inserted to the layout and it is not get focused while on talkback mode:

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:contentDescription="This is the content description"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                android:text="This is the text" />
```

Of caurse that I don't want to add `android:focusable="true"` since it will make it focusable also when not on talkback mode.
Is there any thing I am missing that cause this view not to get focus when on talkback mode?

Thanks

Comment: did u get solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can request focus in talkback mode by following java method.

Trying adding this:

```
view.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
```

from Android P onwards, You can also try this

```
android:screenReaderFocusable
```

OR

```
view.setScreenReaderFocusable(boolean)
```

Comment: @Yaniv did you find any solutions for this

Comment: Just add `android:importantForAccessibility="yes"` to your view's xml properties.

Comment: @deadfish not working this with multiple textviews